# Save an Excel file which contains a string from Outlook2007

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

Im newbiee in VBA, so i need a little help.

My goal is make an Outlook rule, but i have a problem:

I want to save one excel (xlsx) file from my Outlook Inbox to my PC. But only the file which contains (in spreadsheet) a string. But it saves (or not saving anything) the last excel file.. (not checking for `MYSTRING`)

Using this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckAttachments(olItem As MailItem)

Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\PC2\Documents\Temp_attachs\" 
Const strFindText As String = "Completed"
Dim strFilename As String
Dim olAttach As Attachment
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim bFound As Boolean
 If olItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
     For Each olAttach In olItem.Attachments
         If Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 4) = "xlsx" Then

strFilename = strPath & Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd-HHMMSS") & _
                           Chr(32) & olAttach.FileName
             olAttach.SaveAsFile strFilename
             On Error Resume Next
             Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
             If Err <> 0 Then
                 Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
                 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                 bXStarted = True
             End If
             On Error GoTo 0
             'Open the workbook to read the data
             Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)
             Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

             If FindValue(strFindText, xlSheet) Then
                 MsgBox "Value found in " & strFilename
                 bFound = True
             End If
             xlWB.Close 0
             If bXStarted Then xlApp.Quit
             If Not bFound Then Kill strFilename
             Exit For
         End If
     Next olAttach
  End If
 End Sub

 Function FindValue(FindString As String, iSheet As Object) As Boolean
 Dim Rng As Object
 If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
     With iSheet.Range("A:J")
         Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                         After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                         LookIn:=-4163, _
                         LookAt:=1, _
                         SearchOrder:=1, _
                         SearchDirection:=1, _
                         MatchCase:=False)
         If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
             FindValue = True
         Else
             FindValue = False
         End If
     End With
 End If
 End Function

Sub Test()
Dim olMsg As MailItem
On Error Resume Next
Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
CheckAttachments olMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: You can try the code below. Comment if you find any error.

Comment: @Mikku Thx for help. I find a mistake... It looks like I had another `Sheet` name..so, it's saving now the file and checkin' for `Completed`. But still only the last file is saved..

Comment: Try my code. That May work because of the Extra Exit For in your Loop @Georg

Comment: I tried the code in Answer, and it's working smoothly in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your Problem:

You have used `Exit For` in your `For Loop` only. So only after scanning 1st file, loop is exited.

You need to remove the `Exit For` and then your code will work smoothly.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckAttachments(olItem As MailItem)

Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\PC2\Documents\Temp_attachs\" 
Const strFindText As String = "Completed"
Dim strFilename As String
Dim olAttach As Attachment
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim bFound As Boolean
 If olItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
     For Each olAttach In olItem.Attachments
         If Right(LCase(olAttach.FileName), 4) = "xlsx" Then

strFilename = strPath & Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd-HHMMSS") & _
                           Chr(32) & olAttach.FileName
             olAttach.SaveAsFile strFilename
             On Error Resume Next
             Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
             If Err <> 0 Then
                 Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
                 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                 bXStarted = True
             End If
             On Error GoTo 0
             'Open the workbook to read the data
             Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilename)
             Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

             If FindValue(strFindText, xlSheet) Then
                 MsgBox "Value found in " & strFilename
                 bFound = True
             End If
             xlWB.Close 0
             If bXStarted Then xlApp.Quit
             If Not bFound Then Kill strFilename

         End If
     Next olAttach
  End If
 End Sub

 Function FindValue(FindString As String, iSheet As Object) As Boolean
 Dim Rng As Object
 If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
     With iSheet.Range("A:J")
         Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                         After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                         LookIn:=-4163, _
                         LookAt:=1, _
                         SearchOrder:=1, _
                         SearchDirection:=1, _
                         MatchCase:=False)
         If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
             FindValue = True
         Else
             FindValue = False
         End If
     End With
 End If
 End Function

Sub Test()
Dim olMsg As MailItem
On Error Resume Next
Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
CheckAttachments olMsg
End Sub
```